# Hohoner HG-13 strings

Tags: acoustic-guitar, strings

I have an old Hohoner HG-13 which I would like to buy a new set of strings. One thing I saw on the subject was guitars which use vinyl you can't use metal, this one has seems to have 3 and 3. I have no idea if they are the original strings or not. 
If someone can give me some direction I would appreciate it.

P.S. This for for self-teaching home use. Also, I am currently leaning to a low gauge set.
Thanks,
Aba

Comment: You most likely have 3 nylon (rather than vinyl), and the others atr nylon with metal winding around it. So, really, all nylon. It's better that they get replaced like for like, so don't go for steel, but get another classical guitar set of strings. However, Hohner did market this as an acoustic, and some one might have put nylon strings on for easy playing.

Comment: @Tim According to this source http://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Hohner/HG13-Classical-Acoustic-Guitar.gc I would say this standard classical guitar

Comment: @teodozjan - looking at the pic, with the machine heads and bridge, you're correct. Not good for anything except nylon classical strings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was more than likely sold as purely a classical guitar. The strings *should* all be nylon. The 3 lower ones ought to be nylon with a winding of soft metal. That's the only set to use safely on this guitar. The machine heads are the kind that won't stand the strain of steel strings. The bridge is glued to the body - same story; and the neck would probably bow too much, and not be adjustable too.

Comment: Are you referring to http://www.musiciansfriend.com/accessories/daddario-ej43-pro-arte-light-tension-classical-guitar-strings?rNtt=classical%20strings&index=1#productDetail and/or http://www.musiciansfriend.com/accessories/daddario-ej47-pro-arte-80-20-bronze-normal-tension-classical-guitar-strings

Comment: Pretty well any set of nylon strings will do the trick.  Later, when you have more experience, you may get more fussy as to their tension.